# Why might a C-based Python extension always return the same value?

Tags: python, c, python-3.x, cpython

The following code seems incredibly simple. an integer is passed to the function in Python, which creates a PyList in C then populates it:

**hello.c**:

```
#include <Python.h>

PyObject* getlist(int *len)
{
    printf("Passed to C: %d\n", *len);
    PyObject *dlist = PyList_New(*len);
    double num = 0.1;
    for (int i = 0; i < *len; i++)
    {
        PyList_SetItem(dlist, i, PyFloat_FromDouble(num));
        num += 0.1;
    }

    return dlist;
}

static char helloworld_docs[] =
   "Fill docs where possible\n";

static PyMethodDef helloworld_funcs[] = {
   {"getlist", (PyCFunction)getlist, METH_VARARGS, helloworld_docs},
   {NULL}
};

static struct PyModuleDef Helloworld =
{
    PyModuleDef_HEAD_INIT,
    "Helloworld", // module name
    "NULL", // module documentation
    -1,   /* size of per-interpreter state of the module, or -1 if the module keeps state in global variables. */
    helloworld_funcs
};

PyMODINIT_FUNC PyInit_helloworld(void)
{
    return PyModule_Create(&Helloworld);
}
```

**setup.py**:

```
from distutils.core import setup
from distutils.extension import Extension

setup(name='helloworld', 
      version='1.0', 
      ext_modules=[Extension('helloworld', ['hello.c'])])
```

**usepkg.py**:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import sys
import helloworld
print("Input to Python:", sys.argv[1])
print (helloworld.getlist(sys.argv[1]))
```

I build and install using

```
python3 setup.py build
python3 setup.py install
```

and I see no errors.

The odd behaviour happens when I test it. For example:

```
python3 usepkg.py 4
```

No matter what value I give as an argument, the output is always the same:

```
Input to Python: 4
Passed to C: 6
[0.1, 0.2, 0.30000000000000004, 0.4, 0.5, 0.6]
```

The value passed to C is always 6. This is the same whether the input agument is int or Py_ssize_t. What am I missing?

Comment: Isn't there supposed to be at least two arguments to `getlist` since it's a PyObject? The first being a reference to itself and the second would be the argument list.

Comment: From the docs: "There is a straightforward translation from the argument list in Python (for example, the single expression "ls -l") to the arguments passed to the C function. The C function always has two arguments, conventionally named self and args."

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm quite surprised there's no warnings here when building, the types of functions shouldn't be their primitive types but of `PyObject*` -- you'll then parse the types and execute your function

Here's an adjustment to your function:

```c
PyObject* getlist(PyObject* self, PyObject* args)
{
    int len;
    if (!PyArg_ParseTuple(args, "i", &len)) {
        return NULL;
    }
    printf("Passed to C: %d\n", len);
    PyObject *dlist = PyList_New(len);
    double num = 0.1;
    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++)
    {
        PyList_SetItem(dlist, i, PyFloat_FromDouble(num));
        num += 0.1;
    }

    return dlist;
}
```

More information on this can be found in the [parsing arguments and building values](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/arg.html) documentation

---

The number you were getting was likely the value in `PyObject*->ob_refcount` of `self` (the number of references to the C module)

in my case I saw 4 instead of 6, though I'm likely using a different version of python and/or calling approach

Comment: I guess because of the cast to `PyCFunction` in `{"getlist", (PyCFunction)getlist, METH_VARARGS, helloworld_docs},` there can be no warning. IIRC the cast is not needed with your definition of `getList`. So it is probably a good idea not to use cast if possible at all to avoid problems like OP.

Comment: So theoretically, if the function is correct, I shouldn't need to cast when I define my methods?